# Using Apache to proxy requests based on URL parameter

Tags: django, apache, mod-rewrite, proxy, static

I have a back-end application (Django) that requires its static content (assets like images, scripts, stylesheets, etc.) to be served by a web server.

At current, I have my Django application serving on `localhost:5000`. I have this sitting behind an Apache2 server virtual host that is using `mod_proxy` to send requests to the Django app in the back.

I need to configure my VHost so that all of the URI requests for `domain.com/static/asset` will serve the asset from `/path/to/asset` statically, while everything else gets proxied to the back-end app `localhost:5000`.

My VHost config looks like this at the moment, the commented bits don't work properly.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com

    ServerAdmin info@domain.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain_access.log combined

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off

    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
#    DocumentRoot /path/to/static
#    <Directory /path/to/static/>
#        Require all granted
#    </Directory>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm confused about what you're using mod-proxy for. What are you proxying *to*? What is serving on port 5000?

Comment: Back-end web application that prefers not to serve the static resources itself and leaves that job to the web server.

Comment: @Neurax this doesn't answer Daniel's question : why are you using mod_proxy instead of a standard solution like mod_wsgi ? I hope you're not running the django instance on the builtin devserver ???

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers For testing, django app is running on devserver, otherwise will be moved to its own box. I suppose "proxy" is what I'm trying to accomplish, whether it's by mod_proxy or another method... I'm generally unfamiliar and ignorant with mod_wsgi and Apache for the most part.

Comment: The canonical way to deploy Django (or any other wsgi compliant application, which almost any python web app nowadays) with Apache is mod_wsgi : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: Using the devserver is fine for local testing (developper environment) but then you don't need a front server at all, so apache + mod_proxy + devserver is nonsensical. You either run the devserver alone or run a full production setup.

Comment: Forget that it's a django application... What if I want to process requests, have Apache statically serve all reqs to /static/* and pass the rest to X running on another port?